# How to show views to users that was not registered in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel `make:auth` command and email verification of user. Now facing an issue that when any one visiting my web site the authentication will raise and redirect user to login page if the user not register it should register first and verify email before starting to visit my web site. I am wanted to show all my routs to any one without login or without registration. And also i need to verify user email when they register. it showing the routs to only registered and login users, but I am wanted to show every one.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
     $this->middleware(['auth' => 'verified']);
    }
```

after verifying email it shows the routs.
if I comment this code it  will work fine but also i need to  verify email.

Comment: *should register first and verify email before starting to visit my web site*, you can’t block visitors visiting your website without email validating. Since you are not blocking ip, only thing you can do is check if user has validated email when ever user attempt to login to your site. If you want to force users to register your website! Then set a session to redirect login.php all visitors if not registered

Answer (score 0):

this depends on how protective are you with the data to be shown to the visitors.

one method you can try is to use no middleware for those routes you want all of the viewers to visit and use a simple if else condition to show the respective view:

```
public function __construct()
{
 // no middleware
}

public funtion index() {
 if(Auth::check()) {
  return view('logged.blade.php'); // for logged in users
 }
 return view('general.blade.php'); // for all visitors
}
```